# Python how to check if user is in group in view page

Tags: python, django

I'm building a project where you can create and join groups. However, I can't seem to figure out the logic for how to show the join button if the user hasn't joined and the unjoin if they have. I've attached the model and group.html page. Please let me know how to do this in the group.html file.

Thank you.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.TextField(blank=False, max_length=20)
    last_name = models.TextField(blank=False, max_length=20)
    email = models.TextField(blank=False, max_length=20)
    password = models.TextField(blank=False, max_length=20)
    counter = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=True)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(blank=False, max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(blank=False, max_length=200)
    created_at = models.DateField()
    updated_at = models.DateField()
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="creator")
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="members")
    counter = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'groups'
```

groups.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>On Group {{group.id}}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<br>
    <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
    <span>|</span>
    <a href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
        <form action="/leave" method="post">
        {%csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ request.session.user_id }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="group_id" value="{{ group.id }}">
        <input type="submit" value="Leave">
        </form>
        <form action="/join" method="post">
        {%csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ request.session.user_id }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="group_id" value="{{ group.id }}">
        <input type="submit" value="Join">
        </form>
    <table class="table class table-striped table-bordered table-hovered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Group Name</th>
                <th>Group Description</th>
                <th>Group Members</th>
                <th>Group Creator</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>{{group.name }}</a></td>
                <td>{{group.description}}</td>
                <td>{{group.members.count}}</td>
            {% if group.creator.id == request.session.user_id %}
                <td>You</td>
            {% else %}
                <td>{{group.creator.first_name}}</td>
            {% endif %}
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <h4>Members</h4>
    <table class="table class table-striped table-bordered table-hovered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Member First Name</th>
                <th>Member Last Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for member in group.members.all %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{member.first_name}}</td>
                <td>{{member.last_name}}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the variable members? A tuple? A list? A string?

Comment: It's a QuerySet I guess.

Answer (score 3):

You can do a filter like, under templatetags folder in your app folder:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def has_group(user, group_name):
    return user.groups.filter(name=group_name).exists()
```

And in your template something like:

```
{% if user|has_group:'groupName' %}
    <button></button>
{% else %}
    <p> Not in group </p>
{% endif %}
```

Hope this helps.
EDIT: 
May I ask a question that might be helpful for you. Why didn't you use the User model provided by django.auth?

Comment: Won't that just work if i know the name of the group? I need it to work for all the groups that might exist.

Comment: If you have the id of the group you can do the same thing. You just need to alter the filter a little. You can pass as a parameter the full QuerySet of groups and loop over all groups applying the filter.

Comment: If I'm not being clear I can write something that might work based on your code.

Comment: yeah i'm not sure how to implement that. isn't there a more simple way of just checking if the sessioned user_id is in the group and if they are then only show the unjoin?

Comment: I think the cleanest way is the filter way.

Comment: ok. if you can would you be able to show me how to implement it specifically for what i want to do?